# Normal Subgroup Representation Theory

Tags: representation-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $N \subset G$ be a normal subgroup. Show there exists a finite collection of irreducible representations $\phi_i: G \rightarrow GL(V_i)$ of $G$ such that 
$$ N = \bigcap{\ker(\phi_i)}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $N$ is normal then the (left) regular representation of $G/N$ is a representation of $G$. If $H$ is not normal then the corresponding thing is the representation of $G$ permuting $\{ g H,g \in G\}$ by left-multiplication, and its kernel contains $H$ but is larger than it (since the kernel is a normal subgroup)